# Restore flashdrive to original state diskutility

Tags: disk-utility, partition, external-disk, filesystem, disk-format

I have pen drive which has two partitions with almost no storage in each. The full size of the things is 8GB as you can see in the image below.

[image: Partitions & drive]
The problem is `diskutility` commands `eraseDrive` and `eraseVolume` both take as arguments the device **NAME** and **IDENTIFIER** and as you can see in the image above, the different partitions do not have a *NAME*.

My goal is to have a single partition with the full 8GB. Any suggestions?

Comment: The `name` in the `eraseDrive` command refers to the name you want it to be after erasure, not its current name.

The two "partitions" are not real partitions.  They are parts of a functioning HFS format scheme.  You'll always see three "partitions" there for a HFS disk no matter how many times you erase the thing.

It kinda looks like the drive has been mis-partitioned, as IIRC most of the time `Apple_HFS` represents the usable space available -- that is, the real partition that you can use.

Comment: @vykor This should be an answer not a comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command to erase a drive to one (visible) partition is:

```
diskutil eraseDisk FileSystem newVolumeName PartitionScheme diskIdentifier
```

Valid file systems are e.g. JHFS+ or MS-DOS. To get an almost complete list of file systems enter: `diskutil listFilesystems`. If the volume name contains spaces use quotation marks. Some file systems don't accept volume names with spaces. Valid partition schemes are APM, MBR and GPT. Some file systems require a particular partition scheme (e.g. APFS doesn't work with APM or MBR) Use the proper disk identifier by checking the output of `diskutil list`.

So

```
diskutil eraseDisk JHFS+ "FLASH 8GB" GPT disk2
```

would be a working command.

Some partition schemes will create more than one slice even if you chose to create one main volume only:

- GPT: invisible EFI partition with 100-300 MiB
- APM: invisible Apple_partition_map with some KiB